# How can I have a function accepting a function which is the same type?

Tags: swift

In swift, is it possible to have a function accepting another function of the same type as itself?

For example, I have this function in python:
`lambda f: f(f)`

How can I define a function like this in swift? And what will the type of f be?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. For any type `A`, `A -> Void` or `A -> B` is a different type.

Comment: Please give us some concrete usage examples in `python`. `lambda f: f(f)` is a little bit vague.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you question it sounds as if you're looking for a way to define the [self-application combinator (/U combinator)](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/fixed-point-combinators.html#Self-application). I'm not certain it's possible to implement a U combinator behaviour in Swift, but you could, however, dwell down into the related [fix-point combinator (/Y combinator)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) and recursive closures.

---

You can achieve the behaviour of the Y combinator by defining a function that takes a *function to function higher order function as parameter*, say `f: (T->U) -> (T->U)`, and returns *the same type of function*, i.e. `(T->U)`. Using this approach, your function can take functions such as *result from* itself as an argument.

> The short version is that the Y combinator computes the fixed point of
>   a functional -- a function that consumes (and in this case, produces)
>   another function.
>
> The trick is to define recursive functions as the fixed points of
>   non-recursive functions, and then to write a fixed-point finder -- the
>   Y combinator -- without using recursion.

From http://matt.might.net/articles/js-church/.

Now, since you return a function, your return will be "nested" in two steps; the outer defining the return of the closure, and the inner the return of the type. The key is the inner, recursive, return; where you call the input (parameter) function itself without explicitly using its name: you make use of the function parameter which is---as described above---constructed as a closure type that can hold the functions itself.

```
func myCombinator<T,U>(f: (T->U) -> (T->U)) -> (T->U) {
    return {
        (x: T) -> U in
        return f(myCombinator(f))(x)
    }
}
```

Using this function, you can, e.g., calculate factorial of a number without the functions explicitly referring to their own name

```
func factorialHelper(recursion: Int -> Int)(n: Int) -> Int {
    switch n {
    case 0: return 1
    default: return n * recursion(n-1)
    }
}

let factorial = myCombinator(factorialHelper)
print("\(factorial(4))") // 24
```

For reference on the Y combinator and recursive closures in the context of Swift, see e.g.

- https://xiliangchen.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/recursive-closure-and-y-combinator-in-swift/
- https://gist.github.com/kongtomorrow/e95bea13162ca0e29d4b
- http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Y_combinator#Swift

It's the second reference above from which the example in this answer is taken.

---

Returning shortly to the U combinator, there is one simple "native" swift case (however, quite useless) that at least simulates the form `lambda f: f(f)`.

Consider a void function, say `f`, taking an empty tuple *type* as single function parameter. The empty tuple `()` is a type (typealias `Void` refers to type `()`) as well as the single value of that type. Since `f` is void (no explicit return) it implicitly returns an empty tuple `()` as a value.

Hence---although not really related to the U combinator---you could write something like

```
func f(_: ()) { }
var lambda_f = f(f())

lambda_f = f(f(f()))
```

Comment: must myCombinator be explicitly recursive?